# I am getting Chrome Update error though I am using Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between Google Chrome and Chromium (especially with respect to privacy)?](https://superuser.com/questions/220759/what-are-the-differences-between-google-chrome-and-chromium-especially-with-res)

After researching, I came to know that Google Chrome built on chromium, which is a open source web browser. I am not using Chrome, but why I am getting the following error?

> You are using an out of date version of Google Chrome. Some features may not work correctly. Upgrade to the latest version. Dismiss

Is Chrome and Chromium same?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Chromium is the name given to the open source project and the browser source code that was released and maintained at [www.chromium.org](http://www.chromium.org). One can compile this source code to get a fully working browser.

Google takes this source code, and adds on the Google name and logo, an auto-updater system called GoogleUpdate, and **RLZ<sup>1</sup>** , and calls this Google Chrome. As such, everything which applies to Chromium below also applies to Google Chrome, while there are some things that apply to Google Chrome (such as the auto-updater) that do not apply to Chromium.

If you are on Linux and looking for specific differences check [THIS](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ChromiumBrowserVsGoogleChrome)

For full discussion check [this](http://blog.chromium.org/2008/10/google-chrome-chromium-and-google.html)

> *<sup>1. When you do a Google search from the Google Chrome address bar, an
>   "RLZ parameter" is included in the URL. It is also sent separately on
>   days when Google Chrome has been used or when certain significant
>   events occur such as a successful installation of Google Chrome. RLZ
>   contains some encoded information, such as where you downloaded Google
>   Chrome and where you got it from. This parameter does not uniquely
>   identify you, nor is it used to target advertising. This information
>   is used to understand the effectiveness of different distribution
>   mechanisms, such as downloads directly from Google vs. other
>   distribution channels. This cannot be disabled so long as your search
>   provider is Google. If your default search provider is not Google,
>   then searches performed using the address bar will go to your default
>   search provider, and will not include this RLZ parameter.</sup>*

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Chrome hasn't had RLZ parameter since ages.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such warnings and enjoy all the latest features, you should install the latest version of Chromium: [Download](http://download-chromium.appspot.com/) the most recent version for your operating system.

One annoying problem with Chromium is that it does not update automatically, at least on Windows.